# can not output data after clicking submit

Tags: php

i have 3 php files:
1st login-form.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
    {
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    header('location:index-test.php');
    }
}
?>
<form action='index-test.php' method='post'>
Username <input type='text' name='user'/><br>
Password <input type='text' name='password'/><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

2nd index-test.php

```
 <?php
require 'core-test.php';

if(loggedin())
{
echo 'ok';
}
else
{
include 'login-form.php';
}


?>
```

3rd core-test.php

```
<?php
function loggedin()
{
    if(isset($user) && isset($password))
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
?>
```

When i type index.php.It will output login-from.php because i haven't input data yet.But when i type data and click submit it still show up the login form not the messege 'ok'. Where Iam wrong?

Comment: You'll need to grab `$user` and `$password` inside `loggedin()` using [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In core-test.php, you need `$_POST['user']` instead of `$user`; likewise for password.

Comment: it work!. But i don't get it Why it doesn't receive assigned value $name and $password ?

Comment: That might have worked in ancient PHP versions, but these days you need to use the _GET and _POST superglobals, have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant for the form in `login-form.php` to be posted to `login-form.php` itself. If you post it to `index-test.php` as you have done, then `$user` and `$password` would not have been set.

You can follow the steps the others have given, or just change the `action=` attribute of the form, and remain with the existing code.

The only thing you need to do is to change this line

```
<form action='index-test.php' method='post'>
```

to this

```
<form action='login-form.php' method='post'>
```

and bingo!

Hope this helped.

Comment: use `$_POST['user']` and `$_POST['password']` instead of `$user` and `$password` in `core-test.php`. Thanks to @faffaffaff - didn't notice your answer earlier.